# Automatic Database/Table Creation in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a really weird idea that I can't find information on anywhere; I want to make it so when a new "parent user"/"admin" signs up, then a new database is created and appropriate table, this would mean that I would need a command/script to grab the connection string respective to each database and somehow place it into a asp.net web form, surely this would be less complicated than using a token to identify a user than pull all data in respect to them, that way each users data would be stored on a separate database but still have things in common with the main database?

Comment: That is not only weird but also unnecessary. Why would you do that?

Comment: What was the question again?

Comment: im the kind of person that likes to make things over complicated so that it works perfectly in my own special way, it would be more efficient to me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are usign an MS SQL Database then you can create all the desired tables in the model database. This way when you create any new database it will always have the default tables you need.